# WP7 TimeSpanPicker localization (Coding4Fun toolkit)

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I'm using the TimeSpanPicker control from Coding4Fun in my app which is supposed to be translated already ([http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/discussions/256020]). I declared the SupportedCultures tag in my csproj file, but the texts in the timespanpicker are still not translated (all other texts are). Do I need to declare something else in my project?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using short ISO language code try a longer version. For example `cs-CZ` instead of `cs`.